# jquery keyup/keydown trigger not working in datatables having no console error

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

[Image of searched values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsh5u.jpg)
I am working on datatables on which I am receiving data from DB and populating it on search fields accordingly in the table. Now I want to search that data in table and show results. I have data in search fields now I want to trigger keyup/keydown to show result but it is not working. I have used this code to trigger all the data present in search fields but no result or error shows.
This is trigger part of a script which is not working.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').trigger('keyup');
  $('.inputItemName').keyup();
  });
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  table.columns().every( function () {
  var that = this;

  $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
  if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
  that
  .search( this.value )
  .draw();
   }
   } );
```

Comment: Please provide more info. What exactly do you want?

Comment: You need to correctly explain what you are trying to do and what is not happening as your post is very ambiguous

Comment: I am searching data in datatables by retrieving some data i.e. name, gender from a database. now I have values in search fields but the result is not showing because it need some trigger and I am unable to  trigger it by this written code.